# Erro ao iniciar o django

Tags: django

Ao tentar iniciar o projeto no django 1.9.5, ele da esse erro :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fb7346bfc08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
   fn(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/.virtualenvs/api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 45, in inner_run
   self.server_cls = RunserverCommand.server_cls
AttributeError: type object 'Command' has no attribute 'server_cls'
```

já procurei na internet, tentei reinstalar e nada.

Alguem já passou por isso?

Comment: Qual o comando você está utilizando exatamente (puro `runserver`?)? Poste aqui o seu `settings.py` também, por favor

Comment: Se você está usando o **Django Channels**, esse bug pode te ajudar https://github.com/django/channels/issues/696